# Issue with string::operator+=

Tags: c++, string

I tried to append two letters to a string, but it seems that the string is not changed:

```
void fun()
{
    string str;
    str += 'a' + 'b';

    cout << str;
}
```

I checked the source code of STL and found the implementation of `operator+=`, but I still don't know why.

```
basic_string&
operator+=(_CharT __c)
{
    this->push_back(__c);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You do realize that `'a'+'b'` evaluates to an integer, and not to `"ab"`, right?

Comment: what is `str` initial value you are doing `str = str + 'a' + 'b';`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: or more efficiently, `(str += 'a') += 'b';` ;-)

Comment: @TonyD ahaa! this expression looking nice :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Then my knowledge of `operator associative` is poor?

Comment: On my machine the string *do* change, and the result is `"├"`.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin: it's "operator precedence" as well as left-to-right associativity....

Comment: @johnchen902: have a look at http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ - you'll see ASCII values for 'a' + 'b' of 97 and 98 total 195 - the character value for "├"...

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin: no patience required - 'tis all good fun :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By adding `'a' + 'b'` you will have 2 chars added together to form another char. Then you add it to the string with `+=`.

This code will do what you want:

```
std::string str;
( str += 'a' ) += 'b';

std::cout << str;
```

Answer (score 3):

How do you usually put strings in your code?

```
string str = "qaz123";
```

You can do

```
str = str + " another string"
```

Which is (theoretically, in practice it may be anything) an equivalent of

```
str += " another string"
```

You can use

```
str += 'a'
```

because there is an operator overloaded for char type.

You attempt to do:

```
str += 'a' + 'b'
```

Try this app:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << typeid('a').name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid('a'+'b').name() << std::endl;
}
```

The result will look like:

```
c
i
```

Which means, that `'a'+'b'` evaluates to an integer.

**Now the question is: what operator is actually called when you do `str += 'a'+'b'`.**

Most probably the `char` operator is called, with char value `195`.

On my system, the `195` char is `├`. What is it on yours?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't used string here. 
Either use an explicit cast. Or declare it as string variables.

Eg:

```
void fun()
{
    string str, str1 = 'a', str2 ='b';
    str += str1 + str2

    cout << str;
}
```

OR

```
void fun()
{
    string str;
    str += string("a") + 'b';

    cout << str;
}
```

Comment: ``str += "a" + "b";`` - you add 2 pointers here, not strings.

Comment: `std::string` have no constructors with one `char` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

str += 'a' + 'b'; when run this, the single operator '+' is prior to complex operator '+=', so first it calculate the sum of two char symbols, and the sum result is 195(ASCII value of 'a' is 97, 'b' is 98), then run the overload operator '+' of class string. trace into the function, you will find it's only accept argument of char, so it translate into a char with value of -61 (195-256==-61). but it's unprinted symbol, so the result is 0 by the end. of course, you can't get a new string by your desing.

you can recode like this:

```
 string str;
 str += 'a';
 str += 'b';
```

Comment: +1, but a couple small points: it's implementation defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned, so the value could be 195 or -61; "it's unprinted symbol, so the result is 0 by the end" - actually, the string will happily store the 195/-61 value, occupying a single character at `str[0]`, with `str.size()` now 1.  `std::string` can be used to store arbitrary binary content, including NULs, which is convenient occasionally.  Some people do prefer to use a `std::vector<char>` or `std::vector<unsigned char>` when doing that though, wanting `vector`'s interface or as documentation.